# How do I add padding/margin to the left side of the selected menu option in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I have the following exposed dropdown menu that looks like this when an option is selected:
[image]

This is what I have in my XML layout for the exposed dropdown menu:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_menu"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_3">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

How do I add space to the left side of the selected option?

Comment: `android:paddingStart` on `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` should work isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I added that and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks as **Zain** already helped you with your query, I would love to add a few cherries on top of it to make things easy for you in future to decide whenever adding a space-related query comes to your mind.

Whenever we want to have space between two view's we get two options in our mind **padding** and **margin**.

**Padding** is used to add a blank space between a view and its contents.

**Margin** is used to add a space between two different views.

[image]

For both padding and margin, we have two way to set those,

- setting all sides with equal value
- setting side specific values as per requirement

All sides with equal values:

You can use `android:padding="10dp"` for setting padding of 10dp all the sides and  `android:layout_margin="10dp"` for setting margin of 10dp all the sides

Sides with specific values:

**Padding**

- `android:paddingBottom` Sets the padding at the bottom edge
- `android:paddingStart` Sets the padding at the start edge means at the left side of view
- `android:paddingEnd` Sets the padding at the end edge means at the right side of view
- `android:paddingTop` Sets the padding at the top edge

**Margin**

- `android:layout_marginBottom` Specifies extra space on the bottom side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginEnd` Specifies extra space on the end side, means at the right side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginStart` Specifies extra space on the start side, means at the left of this view.
- `android:layout_marginTop` Specifies extra space on the top side of this view.